# Schema.org errors keep popping up in Webmaster because Google won't stop hoarding old webpages

Tags: google-search-console, schema.org

I've been battling Google Webmaster for the last month in an attempt to get rid of all Schema.org errors. I've been stuck between 2-3 errors for the last few weeks. Every time an error is fixed and Google indexes it, it inevitably pulls up another error from a page that was indexed 4+ months ago.

An error just showed up today that was last detected in **February of 2015**.

[image: Google Webmasters Tools, showing URLs and 'Items with Errors']

All three of the pages that I'm currently getting errors for no longer exist and have been 301 redirected to pages that do not have any Schema.org errors.

### My process for removing the errors

1. Redirect the page and wait a couple days for Google to index the changes.
2. *If nothing changes*, I give Google a nudge and have it fetch the page with the error.
3. *If nothing changes*, I request to have the URL removed.

#### Other things I've done

- Every few days I have also been having Google crawl and index my entire site.
- An updated sitemap has been submitted over a month ago.

Google will eventually stop showing the error but I am not exaggerating when I say that I have been dealing with 2-3 errors on roughly 10 different pages for the last few weeks. Every time a page with an error is removed from Webmaster, a new one (or two) always shows up.

Has anyone had to deal with Google hoarding pages? Is there a more efficient way of dealing with this?

Comment: In Search Console, errors do not always go away for a long time. Also know that Search Console can be a couple of months behind on some things. If you properly fixed the problem, then down't worry about it. As a matter of principle, do not try and hurry Google up. If you do a Fetch as Google and Submit to Index, it is not actually doing what you think. 1-2 days later, the regular googlebot will come by and do it's thing. You have to be patient - extremely patient with Google and Search Console. Cheers!!